# Upon entering import nltk in Idle (Python 3.7.4), I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "nltk"

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, python-idle

I have **nltk** installed on my computer (Macbook, version 10.11.6).

The path reads as `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk`.

When I try to import **nltk** using idle (Python 3.7.4), I keep getting the same:

> "No module named 'nltk'"

error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

I have upgraded Python 3.7.2 to 3.7.4. I have also updated nltk to the most recent version available.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of perhaps 20 other questions about failed module imports on macOS, especially when something like anaconda is installed.  You can find more information by searching through their answers.

The prime issue is that nltk is NOT 'installed on your computer'.  Rather, it is installed for exactly 1 python binary, which I suspect is '/anaconda/python3.exe'.  If you run a different python binary, such on the one that come with macOS or one installed with the python.org installer, that does not have nltk installed in *its* `/site-packages`, that *other* python will not be able to import nltk.

When running any python, one can discover which python and it `site-packages` directory by executing `import sys; print(sys.executable, '\n', sys.path)`.  One can then look in site-packages to see what is installed for that executable.

Use `pip` to install nltk for other pythons.

Note that people sometime have the opposite problem.  They install 3.x with the python.org installer, install some packages not included with anaconda, install anaconda, run anaconda's python, and then fine that imports that once worked no longer work.